# xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed

Tags: archlinux, i3wm

я перешел на arch i3-gaps, и у меня автоматически выставилось разрешение 1024x768, но разрешение моего монитора 1440x900, и я создал конфиг для этого разрешения. и вот что выходит

```
$ xrandr --output None-1 --mode "my_cfg" --rate 60
$ xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
```

облазил весь интернет, не смог найти нормального решения. я ставил arch через archinstall, там я выбрал minimal arch, после установки установил все требования для i3 и запустил его.
у меня монитор подключен по vga, но xrandr не распознает его(почему-то)

Comment: а драйвер на видеокарту установили ? что выводит команда: `lspci -knnv | awk '/VGA/,/^$/'`